# Null terminator is removed from string when it is passed to method as a parameter,

Tags: c, string

Note: I can't post any code as it is part of an assignment I am doing.

Right now I have something like

```
int main(){
    char buf[30];
    // Code that reads input and assigns it to buf
    // Adds null terminator to the end of the buf
    foo(buf);
}

void foo(char * buf){
    // Do something
}
```

However when I'm debugging I notice that the value of buf in foo has the string however not with the null terminator. I'm using strcmp to compare buf and another string in the foo() method, and I'm suspecting this is a reason for a bug in my code.

Any ideas why this is happening? (Sorry, I'm still quite bad with C)

Comment: It's not happening. Something else is going on. We can't determine what it is because you won't post your code.

Comment: You removed exactly the part in the code where the issue probably exists. What are you using to read input? Is that method adding a NUL terminating byte (many do) or are you expected to add it? What is the return value of the input reading function? Does it return the number of bytes read? maybe it returns a pointer to the first byte in the string? Consider initializing the `buf` using `buf[30] = {0}`. Also, consider checking for buffer overflows.

Comment: What you describe is *extremely* unlikely. If it's `NUL` terminated in `main`, it will still be that way in `foo`, unless you had some strange buffer overrun issues along the way. More likely, it was never properly `NUL` terminated to begin with. You need to provide the actual code in `main`, because that's where the problem is.

Comment: @Myst This is for a small server so I am using read. I remove the '\r\n' characters from the read in line and add a nul terminator to the end of the string. I'm using eclipse to debug and right before I enter foo(), I can see that buf is how I wanted it, say: "Abc\0"(with some other junk after it) and right when I get into foo() I check it again and buf is now "Abc". Could it be eclipse that is doing this?

Comment: C does not support _methods_. Your code has _functions_.

Comment: There are a few options... Just for example: 1. `foo` might be editing the string (very likely considering your comment). 2. `buf` is shared between threads, and it might be written concurrently  to by a different thread (since you mentioned it's a server)... without code we can only guess.

Comment: @lkjgab Notice that `buf` in `main` and `buf` in `foo` have different types and Eclipse is going to display them differently!

Comment: "and buf is now "Abc" --> what is the value of `buf[4]` when you notice this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am speculating with the amount of information you have given but it looks like your buffer is on the stack and it was never cleared out.  More than likely you have some garbage in it.  You should initialize your buffer with zero's.  Here are a couple of ways to do it.

1. `buf[] = {0};`
2. `memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));`

Remember, that when you declare a variable it will be initialized with whatever value is on the stack at that location at that particular time.  You should initialize all variables to a defined state before you use them to eliminate the possibility of introducing undefined behavior.  From the limited amount of information you have provided it looks like this is your issue.